# Do I need to continue build my model until controller and view or create another model to create associations to each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

In my rails app, I am done creating my first model and the unit testing. What to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example of user and post, the classic example in the ruby guides. My advice would be you want to ensure that users can be successfully created for instance. This entails creating an interface for their creation if it is web then after creating model and testing, creating routes, controller, and view in that order would be great, you want to create the user successfully be continue. We solve small problems at a time. If you going the TDD way then I would recommend outside testing using [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara)